# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geocube.api'; 'geocube' is not a package

Tags: python, conda, python-venv, modulenotfounderror

I am unable to import `geocube` at all in my virtual environment, although I have installed it and my venv is activated.

```
>>> from geocube.api.core import make_geocube
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\andrei.nita\Documents\PG\batch\pgtopy\geocube.py", line 10, in <module>
    from geocube.api.core import make_geocube
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geocube.api'; 'geocube' is not a package
```

What is strange is that if I start a python console from my `env\Scripts` and import `geocube` from that folder...it works. Is there a way to fix the path to the module it self? Is it something related to the Python interpreter? I get this error in the conda environments as well. I am using Python 3.10.9.
My venv has the following packages:

```
(env) C:\Users\MyName\Documents\MyFolder\pgtopy>pip list
Package           Version
----------------- ------------
affine            2.4.0
appdirs           1.4.4
attrs             23.1.0
cachetools        5.3.2
certifi           2023.7.22
click             8.1.7
click-plugins     1.1.1
cligj             0.7.2
colorama          0.4.6
fiona             1.9.5
GDAL              3.4.3
geocube           0.4.2
geopandas         0.14.0
numpy             1.26.1
odc-geo           0.4.1
packaging         23.2
pandas            2.1.2
pip               22.3.1
psutil            5.9.6
psycopg           3.1.12
pyparsing         3.1.1
pyproj            3.6.1
python-dateutil   2.8.2
pytz              2023.3.post1
rasterio          1.3.9
rioxarray         0.15.0
scipy             1.11.3
setuptools        65.5.0
shapely           2.0.2
six               1.16.0
snuggs            1.4.7
typing_extensions 4.8.0
tzdata            2023.3
xarray            2023.10.1
```

Comment: The problem is most likely that your file geocube.py has to be renamed. Otherwise your script confuses your file geocube with the package geocube.

Comment: Ohh, it was so obvious...thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script file name is `geocube.py`, you're most likely importing from your own file, not the package `geocube`. Check out [The Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path). Here is an excerpt:

> When a module named `spam` is imported, the interpreter first searches
> for a built-in module with that name. These module names are listed in
> `sys.builtin_module_names`. If not found, it then searches for a file
> named `spam.py` in a list of directories given by the variable `sys.path`.
> `sys.path` is initialized from these locations:
>
> - The directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified).
> - `PYTHONPATH` (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable `PATH`).
> - The installation-dependent default (by convention including a site-packages directory, handled by the site module).